# What are the physical dimensions of a Wiener process?

Tags: covariance, stochastic-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

I am working with stochastic differential equations (SDEs), which can be expressed as
$$ dx = f(x, t) dt + G(x, t) dw $$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the state of the stochastic system,
$t$ is time,
and $w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a multidimensional Wiener process, $f(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ denotes the system unperturbed dynamics, and the matrix $G(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ determines how the external disturbances affect the system.

I have some trouble understanding the physical dimensions of $G$ and $w$.
I would expect the Wiener process to be non-dimensional, but my confusion arises from the fact that, according to Kloeden and Platen's book "Numerical Solution of SDEs", if the SDE is linear in the narrow sense (i.e., $f(x, t) = A(t) x + c(t)$ and $G(x, t) = G(t)$), the time evolution of the covariance matrix $P$ of the system state $x$ is described by the following ordinary differential equation (ODE)
$$ \dot{P} = A(t) P + P A(t)^T + G(t) G(t)^T $$

It appears that, according to the SDE, the physical dimensions of $G$ must be the same as $dx / dw$, but, according to the differential equation of P, which has dimensions equal to $xx^T$, the physical dimensions of $GG^T$ must be the same as $xx^T / t$.
The only way to obtain consistency is that the Wiener process dimensions are $\sqrt{t}$, but it does not make much sense to me.
Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong? And what are the dimensions of $w$ and $G$?

Comment: Informally, $(dw_k)^2=dt$ (which is almost always true in an average over time intervals), so that indeed one does get some fractional dimensions for $dw$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann OK, this actually makes sense. I incorrectly wrote that, from the equation of $P$, $G$ has the same dimensions as $\dot{P}$, but it is $GG^T$ that has those dimensions. Therefore, if $w$ has $\sqrt{t}$ as physical dimension, everything makes sense and the dimensions of $G$ are $x / \sqrt{t}$

Comment: I fixed the question with the correct dimensional analysis of the differential equation of $P$